# Dialogflow CX agent to transition to another agent

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I can see that we can define routes on the pages and we can choose the transition to another Page or Flow.
Is it possible to configure a route to transition to another agent?

I am imagining a use case where each agent correspond to each type of service in a an organisation. examples like service department, sales department, techincal support team, etc and they want to develop agents specific flows in each of them.

I know we could do all these using multiple flows and pages under the same agent, but was curious to know other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is only possible to transition to flows and pages using routes.

However, if you have your own custom integration or implementation, you can make calls from one agent to another by utilizing Dialogflow CX [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest) and [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview).

For example, using the Dialogflow CX [projects.locations.agents.sessions.detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent) API method, you can set which agent will handle the user’s query by specifying the agent’s ID in the request URL:

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v3/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION_ID>/agents/<AGENT_ID>/sessions/<SESSION_ID>:detectIntent
```

You can get the agent ID in your browser’s URL bar when you access your agent in the console:

```
https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/cx/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION_ID>/agents/<AGENT_ID>
```

You can also get your agents’ IDs by listing your agents using the [projects.locations.agents.list](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/list) API method. The agent ID can be found in the name field of the [Agent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents#Agent) objects in the [response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/list#response-body).

For more information, you can check out the [Dialogflow CX Interactions with the API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about voicebot, you can escalate to a "human agent" phone number and then have separate phone number for each agent. If you're talking about chatbot - I don't no.

Alternatively, you could try [Dasha](https://dasha.ai). It allows to reuse the flows using `import` directive and also has built-in function `#forward()`

https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/built-in-functions/#forward